# How to unveil hidden differences between two apparently identical text files?

Tags: macos, shell, vim, encoding

I have two apparently identical text files, *file1* and *file2*, which contain a very simple shell script.

What I mean by "apparently identical" is that if I edit such files on vim (or TextEdit) the content is shown to be exactly the same:

```
cd ../

mkdir test

cd test

touch aaa
```

(I made sure there are no space/tabs floating around).

It may be relevant to know that
*file2* was created on a different (Windows) machine (I am working on OS X 10.9), and taken from a shared server, while *file1* is a replica of *file2* created by hand.

Now, *file1* runs as expected (by `sh ./file1`), whereas trying to run *file2* produces the errors:

```
: No such file or directory
: command not found
mkdir: test\r: File exists
: command not found
: command not found
```

I observed that:

- the output  of `$ ls -lh file*` reveals a slightly different size:

  ```
  -rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  39B 16 Jul 10:30 file1
  -rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  46B 16 Jul 10:31 file2
  ```
- `$ diff file1 file2` gives the somewhat puzzling (at least to me) output:

  ```
  1,7c1,7
  < cd ../
  <
  < mkdir test
  <
  < cd test
  < 
  < touch aaa
  ---
  > cd ../
  > 
  > mkdir test
  > 
  > cd test
  > 
  > touch aaa
  ```
- Finally, `file -I file1` and `file -I file2` both give

  ```
  file1: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
  file2: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
  ```

I would like to understand what exactly is going on.
My guess is for some hidden encoding issue, but I don't have many ideas as to where and how to look for it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line endings of the two files are different. One has Windows line ends (CR+LF), the other one normal Mac OSX/Unix line ends (only LF).

When you open the files in Vim, you'll see `[dos]` in the status bar at the bottom.

To fix this, execute the command

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Note that the old Mac OS 9 used CR as line endings.